# Properly center search field ( vertically and horizontally )

Tags: html, css

How can I properly vertically and horizontally centre the search field, in this site, in the header?

It is not only an `<input />`, it is an `<input />` with id `#searchInput` and a mic icon to the right ( `#mic` ) all contained in a div, `#searchField`.

Currently I am horizontally centering the form by `top:50%;` and a negative margin-top of half the height. And then I am centering the `#searchInput` with different widths in media queries.

But this seems really improper, it seems like there should be a more proper way.

I've tried `position:absolute;` and `left:0;` and `right:0;`, but that doesn't work and I believe then the #searchInput is shrunk to its minimum width.

I tried giving `display:table;` to the header, `#header`, and then `display:table-cell;` to the `#searchField` and `vertical-align:middle;` to `#searchField`, but that didn't seem to work and isn't well supported it anyway.

**How can I center the `#searchField` in the `#header` in all viewport sizes and in a way, that preferably, is well supported (IE8+ and modern browsers)?**

Here is the page: https://googledrive.com/host/0BwJVaMrY8QdccGkyM0tucHZJNTA/KE_home.html

**EDIT**: So i believe i got it vertically centered now, but not horizontally centered. Meaning it is at the X-axis 0, but not Y-axis-0.

Comment: On the link you provide, the `#seachField` seems to be centered horizontaly and verticaly...

Comment: @web-tiki Yes, but the width is 100%. I want the width to fit to the contents and then be centered.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick. You should be able to able to adjust the height and the width of your search container. If you want the container to be responsive, use percentages.

Iif you would like to center your search bar within the header, make the header section position relative. This should work all the way to IE8

```
#searchField{
  background: red;
  height:30px;
  width:300px;
  overflow: auto; 
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  bottom: 0; 
  right: 0; 
}
```

====================================================
In you case I would do it like this:

section with the id ="input" and absolute center the form. The div(#searchField) should be `position: relative; width: 100%;`.

Your input(#searchInput) should have the following styles:

```
width: 100%; margin-top: 0px; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box;
```

get rid of the background images on the input.

Your submit button(#mic) should have the follwing styles:

```
position: absolute;
box-sizing: border-box;
height: 32px;
font-size: 20px;
line-height: 23px;
right: 0;
```

I have overridden some of your styles whilst bug fixing and it seems that you might have some unnecessary css. Its advisable to clean bits of codes that you dont need at all. Hope this helps. Its also best practice not to use IDs for styling, classes are better for styling and reserve the use of IDs for JS.

Comment: It is closer to the horizontal center, but not there. But it does seem vertically centered: https://googledrive.com/host/0BwJVaMrY8QdccGkyM0tucHZJNTA/KE_home.html

Comment: Just updated my answer with the fixes. Hope it helps.